# Как извлечь одну строку из SQL stored procedure output

Tags: sql, powershell

SQL stored procedure запускает из БД комманду для запуска скрипта powershell.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
    @ReturnValue varchar(max)
EXEC @return_value = dbo.sp_runBatchFile
 @ReturnValue = @ReturnValue OUTPUT
SELECT @ReturnValue as N'@ReturnValue'
SELECT 'RESULT' = @return_value
GO
```

В результате скрипт возвращает данные и мы получаем output в виде таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить значение из 3ей строки, чтобы присвоить его к 'RESULT'?

Comment: Как вариант сложите полученные данные во временную таблицу, а дальше фильтруйте как хотите.

Comment: Не получается. Как это можно зделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table